# Apply US tourist Visa from Sweden while being an Indian citizen

Tags: visas

I am a Indian Citizen working in  Sweden for over a year on work permit . I am planning  to visit USA on a short trip 2 weeks to meet my friend from Stockholm and back.

Is it possible to apply for a US tourist visa from Sweden embassy while being an Indian Citizen ?

Comment: You can apply for a US nonimmigrant visa from any country you're in legally. See [Applying for US visa in Belgium](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45316/applying-for-us-visa-in-belgium)